# Sum of nested object properties

Tags: c#

I am wondering how I can get the sum of the JSON response:

I am trying to get the sum of Delivered so it would be 3435 + 20.

```
{[
  {
    "date": "2016-10-01",
    "stats": [
      {
        "type": "subuser",
        "name": "cooolguy@gmail.com",
        "metrics": {
          "blocks": 23,
          "bounce_drops": 164,
          "bounces": 19,
          "clicks": 0,
          "deferred": 412,
          "delivered": 3435,
          "invalid_emails": 27,
          "opens": 0,
          "processed": 3481,
          "requests": 3675,
          "spam_report_drops": 3,
          "spam_reports": 0,
          "unique_clicks": 0,
          "unique_opens": 0,
          "unsubscribe_drops": 0,
          "unsubscribes": 0
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-10-02",
    "stats": [
      {
        "type": "subuser",
        "name": "coolguy@gmail.com",
        "metrics": {
          "blocks": 0,
          "bounce_drops": 0,
          "bounces": 0,
          "clicks": 0,
          "deferred": 95,
          "delivered": 20,
          "invalid_emails": 0,
          "opens": 0,
          "processed": 0,
          "requests": 0,
          "spam_report_drops": 0,
          "spam_reports": 0,
          "unique_clicks": 0,
          "unique_opens": 0,
          "unsubscribe_drops": 0,
          "unsubscribes": 0
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]}
```

Would I do something like this?  I have tried doing this but it doesn't work I will get the error:

> Additional information: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null
>   reference

```
        string getresponse;

        getresponse = response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        string s = getresponse;

        dynamic o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s);

        textBox1.Text = o[0].stats[0].metrics[0].delivered;
```

Comment: `o[0]` doesn't have a `metrics` property. Look at your structure again. In fact, you don't even have valid JSON to start with.

Comment: @MattBurland Wouldn't it be o[0].stats[0].metrics[0].delivered; ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`metrics` property is a dictionary, that's why you need to access it's values by a key.

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);
var res = result[0].stats[0].metrics["delivered"];
```

Finished edit: You have to create classes to properly deserialize that json.

```
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public string date { get; set; }
        public Stat[] stats { get; set; }
    }

    public class Stat
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Metrics metrics { get; set; }
    }

    public class Metrics
    {
        public int blocks { get; set; }
        public int bounce_drops { get; set; }
        public int bounces { get; set; }
        public int clicks { get; set; }
        public int deferred { get; set; }
        public int delivered { get; set; }
        public int invalid_emails { get; set; }
        public int opens { get; set; }
        public int processed { get; set; }
        public int requests { get; set; }
        public int spam_report_drops { get; set; }
        public int spam_reports { get; set; }
        public int unique_clicks { get; set; }
        public int unique_opens { get; set; }
        public int unsubscribe_drops { get; set; }
        public int unsubscribes { get; set; }
    }
```

After that you can get the sum like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Rootobject>>(jsonString);
var sum = result.SelectMany(x => x.stats).Sum(x => x.metrics.delivered);
```

Comment: Does this SUM them too?

Comment: @JDoe. that should be it

Comment: `dynamic` is Amazing!

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Metrics
    {
        public int delivered { get; set; }
    }

    public class Stat
    {
        public Metrics metrics { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Stat> stats { get; set; }
    }
```

..

```
        List<RootObject> o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
        var result = o.Sum(x => x.stats.Sum(y => y.metrics.delivered));
```